# Change text in an element using only css

Tags: css

Hi I was wondering if it was possible to change the text of the 6th child li in a list to some custom text. Its for a blog for an archives widget. I want the 6th month to just say something like "further back". I know how to select the 6th child I however do not know the best possible way of changing the text to always say "further back".

Any help would be much appreciated thank you.

Comment: And your HTML would be what? And you'd like the text to change based on what?

Comment: And what would happen with the 7th, and other elements?

Comment: doesn't deserve being marked down. He has specified he is using li's and he has said the change is based on it being the 6th li.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could potentially use:

```
li:nth-child(6) {
    /* to hide the original text */
    color: transparent;
}

li:nth-child(6)::before {
    content: 'Further back';
    color: #000;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BVvYU/).

But CSS can't *change* the actual text, as such; it can show this text (but it won't be in the DOM, or accessible to JavaScript, or for selection/interaction by the user).

If the original text is wrapped in its own node, for example a `span`, such as:

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li><span>Six</span></li>
    <li>Seven</li>
    <li>Eight</li>
</ul>
```

Then that can be hidden with the following:

```
li:nth-child(6) span {
    display: none;
}

li:nth-child(6)::before {
    content: 'Further back';
    color: #000;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BVvYU/1/).

As mentioned in the comments, I should explain the use of the double-colon `::`, as opposed to the single-colon `:`, prefix. In CSS the two are used to distinguish between pseudo-elements (`::before`, `::first-line`, `::first-letter`) and pseudo-classes `:first-child`, `:hover`, etc). Under Internet Explorer, which only began to understand/implement pseudo-elements in version 8, *only* supports the use of the single-colon selector (while most other, more modern, browsers support both versions), so it's usually best to bite the bullet and either use: `:before`/`:after` (etc), *or* use both: `::before, :before {/* css */}`.

References:

- [CSS pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes).
- [CSS pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).

Comment: This doesn't remove the other text

Comment: No, I know; but I was working on that... edited to 'hide' the text.

Comment: Seems to hide the bullet too.

Comment: Well, yes. That would be the side-effect of hiding the text of the `li`.

Comment: You might also want to add a note about `:` vs `::`.

Comment: This actually works pretty well. The only issue is that the original text is still appended to the li and thus the container is too big...

Comment: actually, if the height is set and overflow is hidden, this works perfectly for what i am trying to do.

Comment: Nicely done! In which case, I'm glad to have been of *some* help..! =)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a solid background-color:

http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/A622U/

```
.text {
    color: white;
}

.text:before {
    content: "Another text";
    color: black;
}
```